# Enumerated list with square brackets

Tags: lists, enumerate, brackets

I want to make an enumerated list in the following format:

```
[1] foo foo
[2] foo foo
...
```

How I can do that using enumerated lists? I have tried the following:

```
\begin{enumerate}[\left[ 1 \right]]
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Not sure why you want to use the `\left[...\right]` construct, but note that you need to be in math mode to use that so you can use the solutions below with `[label={$\left[\arabic*\right]$}]`.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Use the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to format the enumerated list:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={[\arabic*]}]
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item \ldots
  \item Last item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Note that you are required to encase the optional argument in braces `{`...`}` since it contains square brackets; used in general for optional arguments and would otherwise "confuse" LaTeX.

If you want to make a global setting to your list (rather than the optional argument on a per-list basis), you can use

```
\setenumerate[1]{label={[\arabic*]}} % Global setting
```

or you could make your own list using

```
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{1}%
\setlist[mylist]{label={[\arabic*]}}%
```

which would allow you to use

```
\begin{mylist}
  ...
\end{mylist}
```

Answer (score 36):

The enumerate Package wants you to put those brackets into a group

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[ {[}1{]} ]
\item first
\item second
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Work like charm without adding new packages, thx

Comment: Works also with the `description` list environment, with no need of the `\usepackage{enumerate}` line, then.

Answer (score 26):

[image: Warning]

For the sake of completeness, if you want to change the list format without loading any packages, you can redefine `\labelenumi` as:

```
\renewcommand*\labelenumi{[\theenumi]}
```

For deeper levels, just change the counter, i.e, `i`, `ii`, `iii`.

You might use in a local scope, otherwise this change will be reflected globally:

```
\documentclass{article}

% global change
\renewcommand*\labelenumi{[\theenumi]}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Juventus
\item Milan
\item Udinese
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: List]

To use it locally, you might try:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand*\labelenumi{[\theenumi]}
\item Juventus   % [1] Juventus
\item Milan      % [2] Milan
\item Udinese    % [3] Udinese
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Juventus   % 1. Juventus
\item Milan      % 2. Milan
\item Udinese    % 3. Udinese
\end{enumerate}
```

Again, don't do this, use a package instead. I'd go with either `enumitem` or `enumerate`. `:)`

Comment: @Thorsten: thanks! egreg suggested the text. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda It's clear that text was suggested by a _juventino_: he forgot Inter!

Comment: @PauloCereda Forget it, I haven't seen this is an old post, maybe it was the league table at that time and he's innocent hahaha!

Answer (score 8):

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item[{[1]}] First statement
\item[{[2]}] Second statement 
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using LaTeX Workshop on VS Code. For me the following worked:

I am using `\usepackage{enumerate}` and `\usepackage{enumitem}` with the code below:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={[}\Arabic*{]}]
   \item First
   \item Second
   \item Third
\end{enumerate}
```