# How to numbering subs in a definition nicely?

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate

The code what I've got:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Definition 1.1} The definition contains following contents:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item The first item
  \item The second item
  \item This item may long enough to take up more than a line like this sentence. Line Breaking \ldots
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Result of this code:

[image]

The result what I want:

[image]

The things have to be changed: space between lines, item format.

Comment: Hello, welcome to TeX.sx! `:)` Using the `enumitem` package, you can customize the `enumerate` environment to look like that, say, with `\setlist[enumerate]{label*=(\arabic*),itemsep=0ex,parsep=0ex}`. IMHO, since this change is global and affects all `enumerate` environments you might have throughout the whole document, it would be wiser to create a new list based on `enumerate` (the `enumitem` package also offers you this feature, via `\newlist`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1} % just for this MWE...
\begin{definition}
The definition contains following contents:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*),leftmargin=2cm,itemsep=0ex,parsep=0ex]
  \item The first item
  \item The second item
  \item This item may long enough to take up more than a line like this sentence. Line Breaking \ldots
\end{enumerate}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

You may consider this [Answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42905/enumerated-list-with-square-brackets).

Comment: You might consider adding `\setlist{nolistsep}` to the preamble here to obtain the desired spacing as well. See also @Paul Cereda comment on `\newlist` in case these changes are not required globally. Also: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Added `leftmargin=2cm` as @Jesse suggested.

Comment: Since the `amsthm` package is already being loaded, it would be a good idea to (i) also issue the commands `\theoremstyle{definition}` and `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]` in the preamble and (ii) use the commands `\begin{definition}` and `\end{definition}` inside the body of the document to denote the scope of a *definition*. This would help improve/clarify the logical structure of the document, while obviating the need to engage in visual formatting (à la `\textbf{Definition 1.1}`).

Comment: I've edited your example to include the instruction `\setcounter{section}{1}`, so as to make the definition show up as in the OP's preferred style

Comment: As  to the eye, the most important is the distance from the document's leftmargin to the label, I suggest to use the capabilities of `enumitem` and replace `leftmargin=2cm` with `labelindent=somevalue,leftmargin=!`. This way, the enumerate left margin is calculated from the other parameters. For instance,one might take leftmargin=\parindent if it is not fixed to 0 in the document.