# How to wrap text and put a numbered list inside tabular for publications on CV?

Tags: enumerate, cv

I was making my CV and faced some confusion when making the section for publications. Right now what I have looks something like this:

[image]

The code that generated this is:

```
 \Large{Papers}
 & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l l}
 \begin{enumerate}
   \item Publication 1 dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
   \item Publication 2
 \end{enumerate}
 \end{tabular}
```

What I want is for each publication is to be numbered, which is why I tried using the `enumerate` code, but that didn't work. I also want the text to wrap around.

How would I solve both of those problems? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a minimal working example of your code to your question. And could you clarify what you mean by text wrapping around. Do you mean you want to have text flowing around the enumerate environment or around the table or do you mean the references within the enumerate should should have line breaks?

Comment: For customized ennumeration with `enumitem` see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42907/172164 (`\begin{enumerate}[label=Publication \arabic*]` in your case). In case your second question is about line breaks, the problem you're having is that within `tabular` they do not automatically occur. One way to solve this would be to use `tabularx`, see for example here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166747/172164 .

Answer (score 1):

This is my guess using `tabularx` and a customized `enumerate` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label*=\arabic*.,leftmargin=*,nosep,leftmargin=*,before=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip},after=\vspace{-1\baselineskip}}



\begin{document}

\noindent
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{@{} l >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
  \Large{Papers}&
 \begin{tabenum}
   \item Publication 1 dddddddd ddddd dddddd dddd ddddd ddddd ddddddd dddddd dddd ddddd
   \item Publication 2
 \end{tabenum}
 \end{tabularx}

 \end{document}
```

With `label=Publication \arabic*` as [suggested by TivV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530616/how-to-wrap-text-and-put-a-numbered-list-inside-tabular-for-publications-on-cv/530619?noredirect=1#comment1341826_530619)  you will get a slighly different numbering scheme:

[image]

Comment: I think OP wants labels like: `label=Publication \arabic*`

Comment: @TivV: Good idea that didn't come to my mind. I have included your suggestion in my answer.