# Create a list in the following form

Tags: enumerate

Is there any way to do something like this using an enumerated list:

[image]

It's possible to do this with the exam package and if I have to I will but I thought there might be a way without having to bring in a specific package. In order to get on with the writing I'm currently doing something like this for a single question:

```
\item \phantom{x}

\begin{enumerate}
\item (a)
\item (b)
\end{enumerate}
```

which is far from desirable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enumerated list with square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42905/enumerated-list-with-square-brackets)

Comment: Apart from the specific format requested, this is a duplicate. For your case use `\usepackage{enumitem}` ... `\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]` for the second level enumeration.

Comment: @Munn Square brackets, no I don't think so. I'll try your second suggestion.

Comment: Yes, your second suggestion works, thanks so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily done with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\sffamily
\noindent Here is a list of questions:

\begin{enumerate}[left= 0pt, label=\arabic*., leftmargin=*]
\item \begin{enumerate}[left=0pt, label=(\alph*), leftmargin=*]
\item Here is a question.
\item Another question that is part of Q1.
\item And anotherquestion.
\end{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate}[left= 0pt, label=(\alph*), leftmargin=*, nosep]
\item And it continues, but with Q2.
\item Last question.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
        \item   sub-question a
        \item   sub-question b
        \item   sub-question c
        \end{enumerate}
  \item \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
        \item   sub-question a
        \item   sub-question b
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]